# `ltc target` command won't work

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm trying to follow [this getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-and-lattice/), but I get an error when trying to execute the `ltc target` command (step 1 under Deploying a Containerized Spring Cloud app for Lattice).

The error I get is

> Error verifying target: Get http://receptor.192.168.11.xip.io/v1/desired_lrps: read tcp 37.0.0.0:80: connection reset by peer

My Lattice version is `ltc version v0.2.1` and docker version is `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2.`  I'm running on a Mac with Yosemite if that helps any.